# How do I calculate numbers within my array?

Tags: arrays, calculator

I am trying to make a simple mark calculator and don't know how to take int values from an array.
I'm trying to take all of the values and add them all together: In this scenario, I'm trying to take 4, 1 and 3 and add them together.

```
all_exam_marks = [float(4), float(1), float(3)]
marks = len(all_exam_marks)
print(marks)
```

Comment: To get sum of values in `all_exam_marks` you can do `sum(all_exam_marks)`